# A closest point problem on integer lattices

Tags: optimization, algorithms, discrete-optimization, integer-lattices

This question is an instance of the well-known closest point problem for lattices, but I am having difficulty interpreting the standard complexity results in this context.

We are given a generator matrix for an $m$-dimensional sublattice of ${\mathbb Z}^n$ with $m < n$. But I want to think of this data as constant - so in particular $m$ and $n$ are constants, and you can do as much preprocessing as you like on it.

The input to the problem is a vector $v= (v_1,\ldots,v_n)  \in {\mathbb Z}^n$, and I want to find a closest point to $v$ in the lattice using the $L_1$-norm. That is, a lattice point $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ that minimizes $\sum_{i=1}^n|v_i-x_i|$.

My question is, can this be done in time polynomial in the size of $v$, that is polynomial in $\sum_{i=1}^n  \log |v_i| : 1 \le i \le n $?

Comment: This is much harder in the $L_1$-norm than in the $L_2$-norm (which I mistakenly wrote an answer for, then deleted) because $v$ could be very far from the subspace containing the lattice, and the orthogonal component of $v$ still affects the closest point problem. If $v$ were guaranteed to be close to the lattice (or if $m=n$) then this would be straightforward.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks for your input. Unfortunately $v$ could be a long way from the lattice.

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com may be a good place to ask this question, as experts on lattice-based cryptography post there.